# Mutual effect of model variables

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple GUI I would like to implement via pure AngularJS - there are two (or more) groups of checkboxes like here: http://jsbin.com/cemitubo/2/edit

Here is the code from the link below:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <div class="group">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tag.aaa"/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tag.ccc"/>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tag.zzz"/>
  </div>
  {{tag}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', function($scope){
  $scope.tag = {aaa: true};
});
```

Once A checkbox of one of the groups is checked all the checkboxes of the other groups should be unchecked (and the change obviously should be reflected in the model).

I tried to `$watch` the `tag` model variable and setting false to the variables of the other groups in `$watch` callback. The problem is that it fires the `$watch` callback each time `tag` is changed by `$watch` callback.

What is the proper AngularJS solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-change` instead `$watch`:

Something like:

```
  $scope.changed = function(item, type){
    console.log(item);

    if((type == 'aaa' || type == 'ccc') ){
      $scope.tag.zzz = !item;
    }
    else  if(type == 'zzz'){
      $scope.tag.aaa = !item;
      $scope.tag.ccc = !item;
    }        
  }
```

*HTML*

```
 <div class="group">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tag.aaa" ng-change="changed(tag.aaa,'aaa')"/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tag.ccc" ng-change="changed(tag.ccc,'ccc')"/>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tag.zzz"  ng-change="changed(tag.zzz, 'zzz')"/>
  </div>
```

Demo <kbd>**[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/cemitubo/3/edit)**</kbd>